# Trying to dynamically resize an icon over an image

Tags: javascript, html, css, accordion

I am trying to build an accordion menu. So far so good but I cannot figure out how to centre and anchor the "info circle and triangle" IMG within the middle of the black banner heading. I need it to look like this":
[image]
So then when clicked on, the accordian opens (which I have working) and then the image is switched to the this:
[image]

(Also working). At the moment, after trying countless tutorials I have it like this:
[image]
I need it to resize and stay within the banner when the window or browser is resized. For example on mobile:

[image]

I managed to get it to centre, but when the div enclosing the banner shrinks, that icon stays the same size. I need to scale preserving ratio as soon as the div/window is resized i.e. the two need to be locked. I just cannot get it to scale at ALL, nor stay in place.

I realise I am hacking my way through this -- perhaps someone could offer a more elegant solution?

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

```js
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion_heading");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active_heading");
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.maxHeight) {
      panel.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.container {
  width: 100%
}

.accordion_heading {
  background-color: Transparent;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  transition: 2.0s;
}

.active_heading,
.accordion_heading:hover {
  background-image: url('https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0019/0909/6500/files/banner_graphic_heading_background_brick.png?17876694196823231872');
  background-size: contain;
  transition: 2.0s;
}

.accordion_heading:after {
  content: url('https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0019/0909/6500/files/banner_graphic_heading_white_info.png?17876694196823231872');
  position: relative;
  top: 20%;
  text-align: center;
}

.active_heading:after {
  content: url('https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0019/0909/6500/files/banner_graphic_heading_red_info.png?17876694196823231872');
}

.panel_heading {
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.8s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<button class="accordion_heading"><div style="text-align: center;">
<div style="text-align: center;"><img width="100%"  alt="" src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0019/0909/6500/files/banner_graphic_heading_communities.png?17876694196823231872"></div>
</div>
</button>

<div class="panel_heading" style="text-align: center;">
  <img width="100%" height="auto" alt="" src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0019/0909/6500/files/banner_graphic_heading_blurb_communities.png?17876694196823231872" style="float: none;">
</div>
```

Comment: You should consider not using an `:after` element for this. It's a confusing technique for something that could be more straight-forward.

Comment: With this technique, content is usually set to `" "` and the image would be displayed as a background-image on the `:after` element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the `:after` element position to absolute, move the element `left:50%` to the parent element and `top:50%`, then move back width `translate(-50% -50%)`. Like this the item always moving in the center. 
And change the `:after` element content to `""` and the use the img for background.

```html
 <style>
.container {
 width: 100%
}
.accordion_heading {
    background-color: Transparent;
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    transition: 2.0s;
}

.active_heading, 
.accordion_heading:hover {
    background-image: url('https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0019/0909/6500/files/banner_graphic_heading_background_brick.png?17876694196823231872');
    background-size: contain;
    transition: 2.0s;
}
/*
.accordion_heading:after {
    content: "";
 width:80px;
 height:38px;
    background: url('https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0019/0909/6500/files/banner_graphic_heading_white_info.png?17876694196823231872') no-repeat center;
 background-size:80px 38px;
 text-align: center;
 display:block;
 margin:0 auto;
 position:absolute;
 top:50%;
 left:50%;
 transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
 margin-top:10px;
}

.active_heading:after {
    background: url('https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0019/0909/6500/files/banner_graphic_heading_red_info.png?17876694196823231872') no-repeat center;;
 background-size:80px 38px;
}*/

.panel_heading {
 width: 100%;
    max-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: max-height 0.8s ease-out;
}
.info-icon{
 position:absolute;
 top:50%;
 left:50%;
 transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
 width: 10%;
 max-width:80px;
 margin-top:5px;
}
</style>

   <div class="accordion_heading">
 <div>
  <img width="100%"  alt="" src="http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0019/0909/6500/files/banner_graphic_heading_communities.png?17876694196823231872">
 </div>
 
 <img class="info-icon" width="100%"  alt="" src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0019/0909/6500/files/banner_graphic_heading_white_info.png?17876694196823231872">
 
</div>


<div class="panel_heading" style="text-align: center;">
<img width="100%" height="auto" alt="" src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0019/0909/6500/files/banner_graphic_heading_blurb_communities.png?17876694196823231872" style="float: none;">
</div>



   

<script>
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion_heading");
var i;
var infoIcon = document.getElementsByClassName("info-icon")[0];

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active_heading");

 if (this.classList.contains('active_heading')){
  infoIcon.setAttribute("src", "https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0019/0909/6500/files/banner_graphic_heading_red_info.png?17876694196823231872");
 } else{
  infoIcon.setAttribute("src", "https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0019/0909/6500/files/banner_graphic_heading_white_info.png?17876694196823231872");
 }
 
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling; 
    if (panel.style.maxHeight){
      panel.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
    } 
 
 
  });
}
</script>
```

Comment: Hi NiBa. Firstly thank you very much helping me out. Your answer is just about 90% there. The only issue I have is that the "info circle" image doesn't scale in size as I drag the window around. It stays perfectly in the right location, but for example in my mobile, the image icon is larger than the black bar it is supposed to sit in. Then when I stretch the window very large, then the icon is a little small. Anything else I could do to fix this? Your input is really appreciated. Köszönöm!

Comment: I changed my code above. You need to change the :after element to img, need it a width attribute in %. And need to change the javascript code to change the src attribute.

Answer (score 0):

```
.accordion_heading:after {
    content: " ";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
    height: 25px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    background-position: center;
    background-image: url('https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0019/0909/6500/files/banner_graphic_heading_white_info.png?17876694196823231872');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
}

.active_heading:after {
    background-image: url('https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0019/0909/6500/files/banner_graphic_heading_red_info.png?17876694196823231872');
}
```